# Fragment Intermediate(I):Getting input from edittext, set text in textview of a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext, textview

really in need of some advice, dont know what is wrong here.

Context:
2 fragments with a Textview each and the main activity has 2 button and a edittext

Aim:
Type hello into the edittext box in the main activity and 
When click on the button for fragment 1, the textview will change to hello.

Problem:

Face a runtime error when enter hello into edittext and click on button 1.

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(1291): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1291): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime(1291): android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
E/AndroidRuntime(1291):android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
E/AndroidRuntime(1291):android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
E/AndroidRuntime(1291): android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
E/AndroidRuntime(1291): com.example.FragmentOne.onCreateView(FragmentOne.java:19)
E/AndroidRuntime(1291):android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
```

fragment_one.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:background="#00ffff">

 <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:text="This is fragment No.1"
       android:textStyle="bold" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/easy"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="selectFrag"
            android:text="Fragment No 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="selectFrag"
            android:text="Fragment No 2" />

        <fragment
            android:name="com.example.FragmentTwo"
            android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void selectFrag(View view) {
        Fragment fr;    
        if(view == findViewById(R.id.button2)) {
            fr = new FragmentTwo();

        }else {
            fr = new FragmentOne();
        }
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

   }

}
```

FragmentOne.java

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        TextView monthlypayment=  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        EditText easy = (EditText) inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false).findViewById(R.id.easy);
        monthlypayment.setText(easy.getText().toString());

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the fragment in xml but you also add it to the container programatically. You don't have a container in fact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can add a fragment to the activity layout:

1. Declare the fragment inside the activity's layout file.
2. Programmatically add the fragment to an existing ViewGroup.

Both methods are mentioned in the docs

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

If you want add the fragment to a container you need to use a ViewGroup in xml. Generally `FrameLayout` is used. So have the below in xml

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_place"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

The Activity code is fine. On Button click you replace the appropriate fragment in the container.

In your Fragment `onCreateView` you inflate the fragment layout and use the view object to initialize views of that layout. But you inflate `activity_main.xml` which is not required.

Quoting docs

> Specifically, the fragment can access the Activity instance with
>   getActivity() and easily perform tasks such as find a view in the
>   activity layout

So for `EditText` you can use

```
EditText easy = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.easy);
```

Or Initialize `EditText` in `Activity` on `Button` click get the value from `EditText`and then you can pass the value of `EditText` from `Activity` to `Fragment`

[Send data from activity to fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you for the comment. It not only solve the bug. But it also explain very clearly what a fragment is and how to manipulate things across fragments. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

show me the onclick method, and the container u have fragment one in... its one of two things,

either you are programmatically adding a view which already exists, or you are tryin to update the ui without a handler.... handlers can be worked around in fragments, so im assuming its the first one....