# Add custom view to AndroidTV's Leanback RowsSupportFragment?

Tags: user-interface, android-tv, leanback

Is it possible to add some Views above and between the rows in the RowsSupportFragment?

Comment: Have you checked this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22767439/fragment-intermediate-iidynmically-adding-row-in-a-fragment-android)?

Comment: Hi. My question is about specific RowsFragment of Leanback library for Android TV

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to add any view above the rows by adding view to parent FrameLayout of **VerticalGridView** in **onViewCreated** method. To give space for this view, set proper value for **verticalGridView.windowAlignmentOffsetPercent**:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        (view.parent as? FrameLayout)?.run {
            val myView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_view_to_add, this, false)
            addView(myView)
        }
        verticalGridView?.let {
            it.windowAlignmentOffsetPercent = 30.0f
        }
    }
```

This added view is static and won't scroll out when focus goes down.

Between rows it seems there is no way to add anything but ItemDecorator, because VerticalGridView is a descendant of RecyclerView